# Is there any open source GWT widget that serves a function of "Item list"

Tags: gwt

Is there any open source GWT widget/component that serves a function of a "Item List" that supports pagination, like page1, page2, PREV, NEXT buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following links:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-table/
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-table/wiki/PagingTableWidget

The offer step-by-step tutorial for pagination

Answer (score 1):

[GWT CellList](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html#celllist) is not an option? [GWT CellTable](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) with one column?

Comment: Doesn't CellList support "explicit paging" as well as CellTable?